# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_1" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 32, 160, 1), found shape=(32, 160, 1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, sequential

I am working on binary classification eeg dataset, I used CNN as a classifier model. The size of `x_train` is (960,160) and the size of `y_train` is (960). I worked with `batch_size=32` so I take `input_shape=(32,160,1)` but when I run the model I get this error I don't know how to fix this error, I tried to solve it but unfortunately I failed to fix it. Any idea how to solve it.

**The Error:**
`ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_1" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 32, 160, 1), found shape=(32, 160, 1)`

```
def create_model():
    input_shape=(32,160,1)
    model = Sequential()
    #C1
    model.add(Conv2D(8, (5, 5), strides=( 2,2), padding='same',activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=( 2, 2),  padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())

    #C2
    model.add(Conv1D(16, (3,  3), strides=(1,1), padding='same',  activation='relu'))#incertezza se togliere padding
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.6))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(32, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.6))
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
    
    model.compile(optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adagrad(learning_rate=0.001), loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits = False) , metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.summary()
    return model

model=create_model()
X_train=X_train.reshape(-1,960, 160)
X_train=X_train.transpose(1,2,0)
y_train=np.array(y_train)
X_train = np.stack(X_train)
print(X_train.shape)
y_train = np.stack(y_train)
print(y_train.shape)
history=model.fit(X_train,y_train,batch_size=32,epochs = 200)
```

Comment: The input of your neural netwok is of size 160 and your have 960 inputs/outputs. The input of your model should be (None, 160) or (None, 160, 1). What would hapen if your want to predict ony 1 output? You would input a tensor of shape (1, 160, 1). The batch size should not change the neural network input shape. The batch size is a training parameter.